# Category names on CPT archive pages

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, theme-development

I purchased a theme and I'm trying to customize the "blog archive" pages for the Portfolio CPT that's included with the theme.  The theme is:

http://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/38602.html

I've created some Portfolio categories and linked to them in the menu.  Here's an example:

http://billy.slushman.com/portfolio_category/kitchens

I want it to say "Kitchens" instead of "Blog Archives".  How would I do that?

Comment: This seems like a user support question, which should be directed at the developers. Close Voted.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, but I'm not specifically how to do it on just this theme.  I want to know, in general, how does one do this in ANY theme?  I pointed to this specific theme because I know if I didn't someone would ask for it anyway.

Comment: That's the thing though, it's going to vary by the theme. I can think of 5 different ways to implement that text, just off the top of my head, and the method to change it is different for each one. Since it's a paid theme, you should have some sort of support with it, those are the people who will be able to answer your question...I'd go so far as to say it's impossible for us to without the code for the theme, which is not open source.

Comment: I did end up finding the answer and it was something built into the theme, I just didn't notice it in the documentation the first time through.

As for the original question: this is what I was looking for:
single_cat_title() - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a WordPress that would allow to me to display the category name at the top of the page.  That function is single_cat_title() - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title.